# Can not install libappindicator3-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, 22.04, libraries

I can't install `libappindicator3-dev` on Ubuntu 22.04.

`sudo apt-get install libappindicator3-dev`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libayatana-appindicator3-1 : Conflicts: libappindicator3-1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libayatana-appindicator/+bug/1964964?comments=all) report said that the latest version solved the conflict, but I still get the same error even I use the latest version.
`apt show libayatana-appindicator3-1`

```
Package: libayatana-appindicator3-1
Version: 0.5.90-7ubuntu2
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: libayatana-appindicator
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's too late but I had the same issue.
I tried many stuff only this worked.
So apparently the problem solved with the -y flag in installation.

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libayatana-appindicator3-dev
```

If you have it already try to removing it (with -y flag, if simple remove does not work)

Also these commands will help you verify that the installation is there and valid.

```
pkg-config --cflags  -- ayatana-appindicator3-0.1
dpkg -L libayatana-appindicator3-1
```